# Summation of factorial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I want to calculate the sum of this series:

$$S = 1\cdot1! + 2\cdot2! + 3\cdot3! + 4\cdot4! +\dots+ n\cdot n!$$

Is their any formula for finding this sum?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

$$kk!=(k+1)k!-k!=(k+1)!-k!$$
and telescope.

Comment: So you mean its (N+1)!-1 ?

Comment: Yes it is!${}{}$